# Exception when retrieving record using Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate and have just started right now.

I have very simple table contain Id(Int primary key and auto incremented), Name(varchar(100)), Description(varchar(100))

Here is my XML

```
<class name="DevelopmentStep" table="DevelopmentSteps" lazy="true">
<id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id">
</id>
<property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="100" not-null="false"/>
<property name="Description" column="Description" type="String" length="100" not-null="false"/>
```

here is how I want to get all the record

```
 public List<DevelopmentStep> getDevelopmentSteps()
   {
       List<DevelopmentStep> developmentStep;
       developmentStep = Repository.FindAll<DevelopmentStep>(new OrderBy("Name", Order.Asc));
       return developmentStep;
   }
```

But I am getting exception

```
The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has incomplete content. List
 of possible elements expected: 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2:meta urn:nhibernate-mapping-
2.2:column urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2:generator'.
```

Please Advise me  --- Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the generator type of the id in your mapping:

```
<id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Comment: can you plz tell me one more thing, how can I make a complex queries using HQL in above method that I have posted in my question? like...select t1.ID, t2.Name from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t.ID = 2

Comment: I have seen example on the internet and find HQL but I am unable to use that.........
  public List<DevelopmentStep> getDevelopmentSteps1()
        {
            string hql = "From DevelopmentSteps d inner join table2 t2 d.id=t2.Id where d.id=IDValue";
            IQuery q = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        }

-----here I am getting issue in session

Comment: @Muhammad: Put that in a new question.  Reference back to this question if you want.

Comment: You need to define a class that maps to `table2` that you are trying to join. Then you could have this class as a property in the `DevelopmentSteps` class and when you try to fetch a `DevelopmentSteps` instance NHibernate will automatically generate the join query for you. There are many tutorials out there, google for `many-to-one nhibernate`.